# Science fiction book - defending earth with space shuttles

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

Read this a while ago: the space-opera theme of aliens attacking Earth. The defenders fly "space shuttles" armed with rockets (perhaps originally intended for meteor defense).  Notably the Earth defenders win because the Earth has a power station in orbit transmitting down to the planet via a microwave beam and the mothership/fleet is tricked to fly into its path. I skipped though it, reading bits and pieces, so I have few details.

Edit: LAK answered it correctly (see later): Armada by Michael Jahn of 1981. Page 207 to 208 in the copy I found details the microwave beam blasting Armada. Not poetry by any means, but it was bugging me. All of your help is very much appreciated and I hope I marked the answer correctly (first time use).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be a bit more specific about approximately what year you read this?  Do you remember the cover art of the book?

Comment: I think 'The Foot' has modified shuttles but I think they are using nukes to fire grazers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly [Armada](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1784246) by Michael Jahn?  From 1982.  I recall that the protagonist flies a retrofitted original space shuttle, and there are more modern space shuttles.  They're used to combat a massive alien ship that enters the solar system.  I don't recall whether the enemy ship is destroyed by an orbital power beam, though.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm the answer given by @LAK - I read that book a few years ago and the aliens were definitely defeated by a microwave beam